# Cannot complete React GettingStarted due to babel-plugin exception

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am trying to work through the example [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started), but receive the following exceptions when I run the `npm init react-app my-app` or `npx init react-app my-app` command:

```
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for babel-plugin-named-asset-import@0.4.0-next.14+9802941f.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

From the log:

```
timing command:init Completed in 21468ms
542 verbose stack Error: command failed
542 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\promise-spawn\lib\index.js:53:27)
542 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
542 verbose stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
542 verbose stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
```

node: v18.15.0
npm: 9.6.2

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot this?

Thank you.

Comment: I would honestly recommend not using Create React App anymore; use e.g. Vite instead: https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project

Comment: https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project Recommended list.

Comment: @AKX Thanks, but unfortunately the folks upstairs insist we go with create react app.

Comment: @RobC Well, they're misguided... :) `npm cache clean --force` and try again?

Comment: @AKX Ended up going with your Vite suggestion. If you want to add it as an answer, I'll give you the vote.

Comment: @RobC Glad you got things working. I'm not sure "toss CRA" is an appropriate canonical answer for the problem, so I'll let it remain a comment instead :)